# Access Data in SharePoint Hosted Add-in Web

Tags: sharepoint, add-in, sharepoint-online, hosted-app

I have the following problem. On a SharePoint Online Environment a SharePoint Hosted App is installed that stores it's data in a list.
I need to get data form this list, but the web of the SharePoint Hosted App does not allow any type of access outside of the very same app web / app context.

Is there any solution known for this? I know that the protection of the app web is there for a reason, but I'm wondering if there is really no way that a Sharepoint Hosted Add-In can share Data outside of it's context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get Context of App Web 
var context = new SP.ClientContext("<<SharePoint App Web Url>>");
//Set Proxy web to get data of parent web apps
var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory("<<SharePoint App Web Url>>");
context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
//get parent web context
var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, "<<SharePoint App Host Web Url>>");
web = appContextSite.get_web();

//get parent web list 
var lists = appContextSite.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("<<List Name>>");
var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
//Ceate CAML Query to get items from list
caml.set_viewXml('View><Query></Query></View>');
var listItems = lists.getItems(caml);
//load context of listItems
context.load(listItems);
context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var listInfo = '';
    var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += ' ID: ' + oList.get_id().toString() + '\n';
    }
    alert(listInfo);
    //here you can get list data 
},
function (sender, args) {
    console.log(args.errorMessage);
});
```